# Angular testing error thrown on testing subscribe method under a function as ` Error: Expected spy updateClinics to have been called.`

Tags: angular, karma-jasmine, angular-test

My real method:

```
 postClinicUpdate() {
    this.postProfile();
    if (!this.profileForm.isHfsFormIsValid) {
        return;
    }
    const {
        slide,
        timezone: { codeId },
    } = this.profileFormValue;
    const { sjmAccDTO } = this.userProfile;
    const sjmAccountId = sjmAccDTO.sjmAccountId;

    const postData: UpdateClinicProps = {
        sjmAccountId: sjmAccountId,
        hfsStatus: slide === true ? 1 : 0,
        timeZoneCd: codeId,
        addedClinicIds: this.addedClinicPosProps.appId,
        deletedClinicIds: this.deletedClinicPosProps.appId,
        deletedCountryCds:
            this.profileForm.countrySelectionProps.removedCountries,
        addedCountryCds:
            this.profileForm.countrySelectionProps.addedCountries,
    };
    this.personnelViewDataService
        .updateClinics(postData)
        .subscribe((updates) => {
            if (updates) {
                this.resetPage();
                this.actOfSaveEnabled = false;
                this._location.back();
            }
        });
}
```

equal spec:

```
it('should call postClinicUpdate to save data, and rest the page', fakeAsync(() => {
    const updateClinics = spyOn(service, 'updateClinics').and.callFake(
        () => {
            return of(postData);
        }
    );
    const postClinicUpdate = spyOn(
        component,
        'postClinicUpdate'
    ).and.callThrough();
    const resetPage = spyOn(component, 'resetPage').and.callThrough();
    const btnRemoveClinic = fixture.debugElement.query(
        By.css('#btn-removeClinic')
    ).nativeElement;
    const btnPostClinic = fixture.debugElement.query(
        By.css('#btn-postClinic')
    ).nativeElement;
    profileTable = fixture.debugElement.query(By.css('table#details-view'));
    const checkBox: HTMLInputElement = profileTable.query(
        By.css('tbody input[type=checkbox]')
    ).nativeElement;

    checkBox.click();
    tick(1000);

    btnRemoveClinic.click();
    tick(1000);
    btnPostClinic.click();
    expect(postClinicUpdate).toHaveBeenCalled();
    tick(1000);
    component.postClinicUpdate();

    fixture.detectChanges();
    expect(updateClinics).toHaveBeenCalled();
}));
```

but getting an error as :

`Error: Expected spy updateClinics to have been called. at <Jasmine>`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try changing it to:

`const updateClinics = spyOn(service, 'updateClinics').and.returnValue(of(PostData));`
and add a `flush();` after you call your methode.